# Upload file(pdf,doc,jpg,png) to my local server using php with android

Tags: php, android, localserver

I want to select file from my device(android) then upload in local server using **php** and save its path to my **database**.
Next i want to download it from that upload location.
how can I do this ? help me.

Comment: Just do as you want.

Comment: i want to get knowledge to do this. any link or tutorial that i can follow .if you know please let me know that .

Answer (score 0):

I would use a http request to your php server here is a full working example:
http://androidexample.com/Upload_File_To_Server_-_Android_Example/index.php?view=article_discription&aid=83&aaid=106

To have the client download I would make a /download.php file and use a get parameter to set the database pk to the url they wanna download. next I would read the file and then use the header to change the PHP's output to file so it causes the client to download via http.

CODE EXAMPLE:

```
$attachment_location = "filePath";
if (file_exists($attachment_location)) {
    header($_SERVER["SERVER_PROTOCOL"] . " 200 OK");
    header("Cache-Control: public"); // needed for internet explorer
    header("Content-Type: application/zip");
    header("Content-Transfer-Encoding: Binary");
    header("Content-Length:".filesize($attachment_location));
    header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=filePath");
    readfile($attachment_location);
die();
} else {
    die("Error: File not found.");
}
```

Comment: Of course the line header("Content-Type: application/zip");
will need to be changed to the file type that is being downloaded.

Comment: can you tell me that , cant we just do it like normal data sending to our database . like first i take only the file path from my device then send the path into my php upload file .On that php file using that path i upload the file just like php file uploader .

Comment: When you use a HTML form to upload a file to the server the server then puts the file in a temp directory which is specified in your PHP. Ini and then you must move this file to the folder which you want to store it and then you would save into the database once that is done the location of this file and whatever else you may want to do with this data and file